# can't use android:layout_weight in this code

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use layout_weight in a Linear Layout but it is not setting up proper layout . And showing error.

and how to also showing linear layout error in like a linear layout of relative layout is useless.

And i'm using root relative layout for creating second part of this code right hand side of this linear layout

please help me in this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.android.scorekeepercricketmatch.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/team_a"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/score_minus"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/minus" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/zero" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/plus" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/six" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/four" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/wicket"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/wicket_minus_button"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/minus" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wicket_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/zero" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/plus" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please attach a image, which type of layout you really want?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Problem is not understandable here.

Comment: Try to explain your problem in detail

Answer (score 0):

Layout_weight doesn't work alone, you need to first initialize the value of weight in the parent by android:weightSum="3".

And example to use layout_weight properly:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
android:layout_weight="1"
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="0dp"/>

<TextView
android:layout_weight="1"
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

One thing to note here is that when you are using layout_weight for equally dividing screen then you should 0dp in that particular field(height or width) because if you use wrap_content or match_parent then it will get confuse what to take.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/team_a"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/score_minus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/minus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/zero" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/plus" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/six" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/four" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/wicket"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/wicket_minus_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/minus" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/wicket_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/zero" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/plus" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace your layout with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a little resume about how `weights` are used:

There are two properties. One is the [layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) and the other one is [weightsum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum)

In a `container` (a `lineaLayout`) You should set a `layout_weightsum`

**This property is the total amount of `weights` you are using inside this `layout`.**

For example: You have a `linearlayout` with two `items`, and both items have to have the same `height`.

You will set a sum of 2 and for each layout a `weight` of 1 (or 3-1,5 / 4-2... it accepts also decimals).

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="2">

  <!--Item1 (might be TextView, another LL, a RL, Button,...)-->
   <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   />

  <!--Item2 (might be TextView, another LL, a RL, Button,...)-->
   <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will result in a `LinearLayout` with two items taking all available space.

Now some notes: The item having the weight set, should have the width (if orizontally set) or the `height` (if vertically set) set to `0dp`. this because the `weight` is setting this property on his own.

Another note is that this can't be done in `RelativeLayouts` but only in `LinearLayouts` because they have no orientation, no gravity and no order by default.

The final note is that the weights total sum inside a layout can be more, less or equals of the weightsum you set in the container itself. This depends only on your needs.

Hope this helps. for more informations [you can see the official guide right here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

From the doc:

> Equally weighted children
>   To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1".

Answer (score 0):

you can't give `layout_weight` when parent is `RelativeLayout`. Make your parent layout Linearlayout, define `android:weight_sum` in parent and add `layout_weight` in children. Don't forget to make your child height or width `0dp` according to your layout orientation.

Comment: No you're wrong. You can do same with RelativeLayout also.

Comment: Dear Mr right, refer to this official docs. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html